# Where can I find my wishlist when browsing the Playstation store?

Tags: ps3

I like to keep track of the games I want to buy sometime down the line. Since most of said games are on steam, that's a rather easy task. However, there are also some games I want to pick up for my PS3 in the future.

I've set up my wishlist by logging into the [PSN's website](http://us.playstation.com/psn/), but when I browse the Playstation store on my PS3 I can't seem to locate that wishlist anywhere.

Where is that wishlist hiding, if anywhere at all?

Comment: I'd like to know this myself. I actually really don't like the setup for the Playstation Store. It should be easier to view items you've already purchased as well (an "Owned" section or something) instead of having to browse through everything you've ever downloaded...

Answer (score 1):

I've found my shopping wish list by going to My Profile, then on the right side there's a section called quick links. Click "My Games" and your wish list should be in there also.

Comment: Is this on the PSN website? I'm talking about browsing the store through the PS3 itself.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, thats on the website. Ive not seen anything on the PS3 yet.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you need a degree to find the bookmarks (not the wish list) on the PS4. The bookmarks are accessible from the console. Go to Profile within you PS4 and if there are no links to the right look to the left and scroll down the list to "Recent Activity." If you have previously added a fresh bookmark then it will show on the list "Such and such likes..." Click on the link and then you can use your triggers to scroll through the bookmarks. It would be nice if there was a direct link within the PS Store "Bookmarks. That is 30 minutes I can't get back.

Answer (score 0):

you can find it on an old non updated android system, I did it with my Gal Note 10.1 2014 edition. I used the non updated psn app to get the store...it looks like a wrong web address, but you can find the “❤️“ icon, and u csn press it, I get my old wlistPS3 games as well[image]